# Error calling function from another fragment Java

Tags: java, android

I have an app for Android and I need to call a specific function to update my GridAdapter of the gallery that I made

my update function that I want to call it in other classes is this one

GrideAdapter.class

```
public void updateGride(){
}
```

the code works right of the update function but everytime I call that function from another class it gives me an error and app stop working 
this is how I do call the function from the other class

```
GridAdapter ab;
ab.updateGride();
```

what I do wrong? why I can't use the updateGride function in other fragment classes?

Comment: pass the context as parameter.

Comment: From your code above it seems you didnt initialize ab (tell us if that's not the case). I hope you are seeing NullPointerException? If not what's the exception you see?

Comment: right, I think you need initialize ab.

Comment: @almasshaikh yes im getting NullPointerException , the inialize for ab that I did is  GridAdapter ab = new GridAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), files, gridView);
                 ab.updateGride(getActivity().getApplicationContext());  // it's still doesn't work it give nullPointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its already been answered in the comments.

You need to initialize an object before using any of its members (non-static). This is basics of oop, its not specific to android or java. This is what you need,

```
    GridAdapter ab = new GridAdapter(/*arguments*/);
    ab.updateGride();
```